# Trying to install Laravel - cURL not found

Tags: php, linux, curl, laravel, apt-get

Hi all I'm trying to set up a LAMPP server on a Debian 7.2 VM guest ran from a win7 host all 64bit.  I want to install the Laravel framework.  I have got to the stage to install cURL to then get composer.  I have installed it (originally from my linux distro iso dvd) and it appeared to install with no errors.  However whenever I try to execute a curl command it says

```
bash: command not found
```

so I then did:

```
apt-get update
apt-get libcurl3 php5-curl
```

again it says they are already installed but are all up to date.  Im fairly new to *nix environments so I'm probably looking oversomething.  Whenever I try to execute from  terminal it always says they aren't to be found.  Ive tried su, and su - to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try simply `apt-get install curl`.